# Recreating index on model change with Hibernate Search

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search

I am using Hibernate Search in my application and at the moment I am recreating index every time application is restarted.

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
```

I would like to stop doing that and recreate index only when my model changes. Is there a common pattern to implement that behavior? I did not manage to find anything.

Comment: Hi Mag, were you able to find the answer to this? I am also stuck with something similar

Comment: Hi Nishant, no, I guess you need to build something on your own.